# Solstice dates on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm in the process of putting together an app that makes use of the Suns position at both the Summer and Winter solstice. While there is plenty of tables of data out there, I'm wondering if there are any standard iOS components that can be used to calculate or retrieve the solstice dates without having to embed and then lookup the data.

Comment: I would think that they occur at regular intervals in terms of seconds since some reference date.  NSDate will give you seconds since a reference date.

Comment: There is nothing built into iOS that will give you these calculations. A few minutes with Google will turn up lots of pages with algorithms. Don't limit your search to Objective-C code. You may find the algorithms in Javascript or other languages. They should be easy enough to convert to Objective-C - it's mostly basic math and some date calculations.

Comment: Also, all of your Obj-C apps can use straight C, making @rmaddy 's approach even easier.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I ended up doing. I'll post the code in an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking advice from the comments, the following is what I implemented to get the gregorian date with hours and minutes from a julian date.

```
- (NSDate *) dateFromJulianDate:(double)julianDate
{
  NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
  NSDate *gregorianDate;

  double datePart = floor(julianDate);
  double timePart = julianDate - datePart + 0.5;

  // Really the next calendar day?
  if (timePart >= 1.0) {
    timePart = timePart - 1.0;
    datePart = datePart + 1;
  }

  double l = datePart + 68569;
  double n = floor (4 * l / 146097);
  l = floor(l) - floor((146097 * n + 3) / 4);
  int year = floor(4000 * (l + 1) / 1461001);
  l = l - (floor(1461 * year / 4)) + 31;
  int month = floor(80 * l / 2447);
  int day = l - floor(2447 * month / 80);
  l = floor(month / 11);
  month = floor(month + 2 - 12 * l);
  year = floor(100 * (n - 49) + year + l);
  double hour = timePart * 24.0;
  double minutePart = hour - floor(hour);
  hour = floor(hour);
  double minute = minutePart * 60;
  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  [dateComponents setYear:year];
  [dateComponents setMonth:month];
  [dateComponents setDay:day];
  [dateComponents setHour:hour];
  [dateComponents setMinute:minute];
  [dateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
  gregorianDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

  return [gregorianDate copy];
}
```